# how to fetch old RSS feeds from movabletype site?

Tags: rss, feed, movabletype

Is there any instructor for that? I mean some way to access other pages of movabletype feed?

Example:

```
MovableTypeSite/feed/page=10
```

or

```
MovableTypeSite/feed/rss?page=7
```

Comment: You failed to mention whether this is an installation you control or someone else’s.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the default static publishing scheme of Movable Type, your feeds are static files that cannot be modified through URL parameters. The feeds by default contain the last 15 entries, but you could increase this number by modifying the default "Feed - Recent Entries" template of the blog in question.

You could change `<mt:Entries lastn="15">` to `<mt:Entries lastn="60">` or `<mt:Entries days="60">` or use any of the [attributes of the Entries tag](http://movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/tags/entries.html) to customize your output.

It would also be possible to set up "paginated" feeds, such as a per month feed. You could start with the default feed index template referenced above and copy it into a new archive template of the type "Entry Listing".

Answer (score 1):

A little-known feature of Movable Type's search is that it supports multiple templates and by default includes a feed template. In the search results URL, you can specify a `page=2` argument (or whatever page). Of course, the trick is that you need a search term -- which may or may not work well for your use.

The URL: `[MT Home]/mt-search.cgi?limit=20&Template=feed&search=test&page=2`

Answer (score 0):

Use  in the template generating the feed (a number superior to the number of entries in the system), publish it, and voilà.